# Java process execute "tail -f test.log | grep abc" can't not get any output

Tags: java, linux, bash, shell

I've written a java program to execute linux command. But I find it can not get any output from the command "tail -f test.log | grep abc"

Below are several examples:

```
"tail -n 100 test.log | grep abc" -- works
"tail -f test.log" -- works  
"tail -f test.log | grep abc" -- not works
```

My Java code

```
String[] cmd = new String[] {"/bin/sh", "-c", "tail -f /Users/Alexis/Test/test.log | grep abc"};
InputStream inputStream = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd).getInputStream();
byte[] bb = new byte[8];
int i = 0;
while ((i = inputStream.read(bb)) != -1) {
    System.out.println("received : " + new String(bb, Charsets.UTF_8));
}
```

When I echo something into test.log, I can't get any output.

Comment: Since tail -f is not terminating, the data may be still in the pipe buffer. Can you try "unbuffer tail -f test.log | grep abc"?

Comment: @ManuelBarbe I've tried but it did not work :(

Comment: Are lines with `abc` still being appended to test.log while your program is running? As if not and there are `abc` lines in the last 100 lines but not in the last 10 or so - it'd explain exactly what you see. Do you see the same behaviour when running the cmds manually in a terminal? Just trying to rule out the obvious...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally I use 'tail -f test.log | unbuffer -p grep abc' and it works

Also, you can use 'tail -f test.log | stdbuf -o0 grep abc'